# Keyboard shortcut to focus application's search bar (not Spotlight) in macOS?

Tags: macos, keyboard

If keyboard shortcuts are enabled in gmail, pressing <kbd>/</kbd> will focus the search bar from anywhere, so that I can simply type `/stuff` to search for "stuff" no matter what is currently focused.

Is there a similar keyboard shortcut to focus the search bar within applications (not spotlight)?

---

*Note:* I'm looking for an alternative to hitting <kbd>tab</kbd> repeatedly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe there is a system-wide shortcut for this, as the definition of Search Bar may not be standard across apps. But hitting <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> focuses the Search Bar in many Mac applications.

Answer (score 3):

As already noted, most applications use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> for search. However, in some applications <kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> triggers the main search dialog (e.g., iTunes) or a secondary form of search (e.g., Excel, Finder, Safari, Chrome).